# Go template include external css

Tags: go, go-templates

index.go

```
package main
import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)
func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
    t.Execute(w, nil)
}
func main() {
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
    http.HandleFunc("/index", viewHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

In my index.html, I used the following path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css">
```

And the path for the .css is as follows,

web(folder)

|---index.go

|---static/css/xxx.css

But, the css is not included in the html. How can I change the code to fix this problem

Comment: What do you mean "not included in html"? According to the code, the server should serve the CSS file under `serveraddress.com/static/css/bootstrap.css`, not include it in anything. I'm pretty sure the file names you've written here are wrong. "index.go"?

Comment: @Staven Sorry, that is main.go. Actually, when I click http://localhost:8080/static/css/bootstrap.css, it tells 404 error. How can I fix it?

Comment: @Wyatt I've just tested your code and it serves the CSS file correctly on my machine. Are you sure you don't have any conflicts with port 8080 on your machine?

Comment: @Intermernet Thank you very much. I changed it to 8090 and this problem is fixed

Answer (score -1):

Because of the conflicts of the port, the CSS file is not correctly included. Thanks to @Intermernet. :)